# Migration of code Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle

oracle code

```
  select PERSONID 
  into v_personID
  from HAIL_ESS_USERS_EXTENDED_V
  where EID = p_eid
  and     IS_ACTIVE = 'Y'
  and rownum = 1;
```

sql server code

```
set @v_PersonId = (select PersonId 
               from   viwSSAppsEmpMasterExtended
               where  EID = @p_EID
               and    IsEmployeeActive = 'Y'
               and    @@rowcount=1)
```

is this right or there may some changes required...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`@@ROWCOUNT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) does not work like this, `@@ROWCOUNT` will return the number of rows affected by the previous statement, so in the following example:

```
SELECT  A = 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1;

SELECT  *
FROM    (select A = 1 union all select 1) AS t
WHERE   @@ROWCOUNT = 1;
```

Because the first statement returns two rows, the second returns none (because `@@ROWCOUNT` = 2, not 1). If you just want to get the first result you need to use [`TOP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx):

```
set @v_PersonId = (select top 1 PersonId 
                   from   viwSSAppsEmpMasterExtended
                   where  EID = @p_EID
                   and    IsEmployeeActive = 'Y')
```

However, in the absence of an `ORDER BY` clause, `TOP` is farily meaningless, you could feasibly run this query 10 with the same data and get 10 different people.

Comment: `ROWNUM` is fairly meaningless in the Oracle query too. If the Oracle query is working as expected, then it's fair to assume that there's only one distinct value of `PersonID` being returned, and therefore `TOP 1` will do just as well in the SQL Server query. Upvoted for bothering to explain your answer, unlike me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `top` instead of `@@rowcount` in your sql server query:

```
set @v_PersonId = (select top 1 PersonId 
                   from   viwSSAppsEmpMasterExtended
                   where  EID = @p_EID
                   and    IsEmployeeActive = 'Y')
```